# Drupal 7 - after successful install, seemingly random action creates permanent server error

Tags: drupal, server-error

I am working with Drupal (7) for the first time. I have installed it multiple times using both an automated Simple Scripts method, and a manual method. I am using the MERCI module to create a reservation system. Every time, over the course of several installations, a seemingly simple action - such as creating a taxonomy term (most recent trigger) or activating a standard module (Views for instance) results in a permanent 500 Server Error, interspersed with a properly loaded home page that will not allow the user to proceed to further links.

Check out the site here: www.browntv.org/mgmt

On first load - you will either get a Server Error, or a properly loaded page. If the page loads properly, clicking to ANY link should result in a blank screen, server error, or some other redirect.

I honestly don't even know where to start diagnosing this. I can't tell where an error (if there was one) would be logged, and nor can I figure out how to manually step my MySQL database backwards to try and remove whatever is causing the issue.

Any leads, suggestions, or ideas would be REALLY helpful. Until now, I've just been creating a new installation, thinking that the issue stems from installation issues. However it has happened so many times now I can't just keep starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not seeing any errors on your site, and in fact it let me register a new account.

Having said that, as should be obvious from the error message, 500 is an *internal* server error, and no one is going to be able to determine the cause just by going to the public url. It's an error with a configuration file on your server. Generally a syntax error would give you a consistent, not a sporadic 500.

While I have a good deal of experience with MERCI, the way you've described the issue, that wouldn't have anything to do with it.

If the problem persists you should check your Apache error log.

Comment: Thank you. I seemed to have resolved the issue by stepping down to Drupal 6 - which is where you were able to register. Clearly an internal server error is undiagnosable from a public URL - I merely wanted to see if this was an issue others had experienced. All seems to be well for now though.